# Throw a fair die once, describe the $\sigma$-algebra in terms of the events $A$ and $B$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Problem: Throw a fair die once. Assume we only can observe if the number obtained is "small", $A = \{1,2,3\}$, and if the number is "odd", $B = \{1,3,5\}$. Describe the resulting probability space; in particular describe the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ generated by $A$ and $B$ in terms of a suitable partition of the sample space.

Sol: The probability space is $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P} \}$, where $ \Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is a discrete uniform distribution since it's a fair die.

We can observe the events:

small; $A \in \mathcal{F}$, not small; $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$; odd; $B \in \mathcal{F}$, not odd; $B^c \in \mathcal{F}$.

The smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A,B$ is $ \{ \varnothing, A, A^c, B, B^c, A \cup B, A \cup B^c, A^c \cup B, A^c \cup B^c, \Omega \}.$

Does this $\sigma$-algebra coincide with the possible observations:

Small; not small, odd, not odd, small or odd, small or not odd, not small or odd, not small or not odd.

Is this correct, and what kind of observation does $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$ coincide with?

Comment: You haven't listed the intersections. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\emptyset$ is, as in all sigma algebras, the "impossible event". For example, it is equal to the event "small **and** not small" (since $\emptyset=A\cap A^c$), or to the event "even **and** odd".

$\Omega$ is, as in all sigma algebras, the event that always happens. For example, it is equal to the event "small **or** not small" (since $\Omega = A\cup A^c$), or to the event "even **or** odd"